# Filtering for a column for all rows that have a specific string in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get all unique values in a column that have a specific word in it,

for example if I want to find all values that have the word bird in it, regardless of Capitalization of first letter or not, how can I filter for that?

`df.animal.unique()` would give me all unique values in the column but I want only the ones that have Bird in the string or name if that makes sense, Thanks!

DF

```
 | Animal |
Eagle Bird
PigeonBird
Whale Fish
Dolphinfish
peacockbird
hawkBird
Falc Bird
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Sorry I dnt have sample currently but I added a example of dataset df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because need:

> I want to find all values that have the word bird in it, regardless of Capitalization of first letter or not

use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with both words:

```
df = df[df.Animal.str.contains('bird|Bird')]
```

Or:

```
df = df[df.Animal.str.contains('[bB]ird')]
```

---

```
print (df)
        Animal
0   Eagle Bird
1   PigeonBird
4  peacockbird
5     hawkBird
6    Falc Bird
```

Comment: thanks! If some values have a space between other words or not like in sample data set that is fine correct? Like Eagle Bird and PigeonBird @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - not sure if understand, do you need only words with space, like `Eagle Bird` and `Falc Bird` ?

Comment: No sorry for confusion, I want all strings or rows where Bird or bird appears regardless if it has that space inbetween other words or not @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - Can you add expected output? Do you need unique words contains `bird` word?

Comment: Yes! I think your answer is correct because it returns all cells that contain Bird or bird,  as I wanted just all words in the column that contain the word bird anywhere in that column value whether starts with capital letter or not and has spaces between other words or not @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - yop, if need all rows then answer working, but if need `['Bird', 'PigeonBird', 'peacockbird', 'hawkBird']` answer should be changed

Comment: No just all rows that contain the Bird or bird anywhere in the cell @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Try using `str.contains`

```
df[df.animal.str.contains('bird', case=False)]
```

Comment: OP need `Capitalization of first letter`

Comment: Well it's not clear from `regardless of Capitalization of first letter or not`. Maybe data contains other letter also in caps.